# I am signed as root but no root home directory exist, that probably prevents me creating a new user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users, root

I have a problem. When I enter a Ubuntu machine, I see this messages:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/root: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/root/.Xauthority
```

When I make `whoami`, I receive the answer: `root`

but no directory /home/root exist.

When I am trying to create a new user: `adduser blabla`, I receive this error:

```
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
```

When I am trying to create it in a different way: `useradd -m blabla`, I receive:

```
useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

someone can explain me what went wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you connecting to a remote machine via ssh?  Or is this a local machine?  ... There typically is no `/home/root` directory.  The root home is typically located at `/root`  From the error messages, it would appear that you are not the root user for the system.  Did you create a user named `root`?

Comment: I did log in to a machine. It may be indeed a root user created, but not by me - I am checking it now

Comment: Can I remove it safely using "sudo userdel root"?

Comment: "Can I remove it safely using "sudo userdel root"?" No it hurts..., if you dont need root just block root user with the command passwd -l root (l = lowercase L) .... and if you have ssh, change PermitRootLogin to no for guarantee... If the actual root user is not working properly edit /etc/passwd and change UID and GID to 0 ...

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/passwd | grep root` ... it should look almost identical to this: `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

Answer (score 3):

Try to figure out what is your current id (by issuing id command in shell), user root should have uid=0. 
If your uid is different from 0, you is not under privileged account.
Also, what`s happening if you issue command sudo -i ?